# Skyrim CTD during intro sequence after clean install

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

After experiencing some problems with Skyrim and my mod loadout after installing Dragonborn, I figured the easiest way to fix everything would be to start from scratch, so I uninstalled Skyrim (and manually deleted the left over files).

I then proceeded to re-download and install Skyrim, Dawnguard, Hearthfire and Dragonborn, and the Hi Res texture packs - all official Bethesda content, no mods.

I can get into the game, and start a new game, but after about 10 seconds on that darned cart, the game crashes.

I'm fairly certain all my drivers and whatnot are up to date, and my computer is enough to handle Skyrim no problem.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: After deactivating the high resolution DLC and unofficial patch, I was able to play for about half an hour before it crashed.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but this happened to me back when Skyrim just came out, I had the vanilla version and it would crash during autosaves and at certain locations. Funny thing is, all I did to fix it was change the resolution. NOTE: My computer can handle Skyrim at ultra settings but some bug caused it to crash. I haven't encountered similar issues since then.

Comment: This is having no effect, sadly. Thanks though

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If yes, I found a new mod that might help in avoiding CTDs in Skyrim: [SSME - Skyrim Startup Memory Editor](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50305/?) (editing this into my answer). You might want to try it.

Comment: @galacticninja thanks - I appreciate the updated info, and anything which adds stability to my Skyrim is worthwhile to me. I haven't played in a few months but I did resolve the problem in the end using Live Another Life I believe, as per my comments on your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try also installing the Unofficial [Skyrim](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19), [Dawnguard](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/23491), [Hearthfire](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/25127), [Dragonborn](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31083) and [High Resolution DLC](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31255) patches. They fix a lot of bugs within the game and the DLCs, preventing some of the possible crash reasons.

If it still crashes, skip the opening sequence by using the **[Alternate Start - Live Another Life](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/9557)** mod.

> Live Another Life provides an alternative means to start the game for those who do not wish to go through the lengthy intro sequence at Helgen. You will be given the opportunity to choose your race and then choose a new life for your character to lead. A wide variety of choices will be available.

Another mod that you might want to try is: [**SSME - Skyrim Startup Memory Editor**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50305/?).

> This… patch will allow Skyrim to use… available space right from the start to fix ILS (infinite loading screen) without side effects and other memory related CTD (crashes to desktop) or freezes.
>
> When tesv.exe is started it allocates two 256MB blocks of memory. When the first block gets full, the engine will allocate more blocks. This can cause the known troubles. Thankfully, by telling the engine to request a bigger block from the start it magically makes use of it without any further ado. This isn't the case with the second block. Thankfully again, the second block does not fill up as quickly and once it is full the engine does not trip over itself when allocating more blocks.
>
> To make the engine allocate a larger block of memory it needs to be patched.

Also, use **[BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/6)** to optimize the load order of the mods and DLCs.

> BOSS is designed to assist mod users in avoiding detrimental conflicts, by setting the correct load order for the plugins they have installed.
>
> BOSS also provides thousands of plugin-specific messages, including usage notes, Bash Tag suggestions, requirements, incompatibilities, bug warnings and installation mistake notifications.

If it still crashes, I'd recommend "cleaning" the DLCs.

- [More about cleaning mods and the DLCs with TES5Edit](http://www.creationkit.com/TES5Edit_Cleaning_Guide_-_TES5Edit)
- [Tutorial on cleaning mods and the DLCs using TES5Edit](http://www.creationkit.com/TES5Edit_Mod_Cleaning_Tutorial#Quick_List_of_What_.26_What_Not_to_Clean)
- [**TES5Edit** download link](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/25859)

Comment: Do you find it's better to install these using NMM or Steam Workshop?

Comment: I reinstalled the unofficial patches and Live Another Life (6 of my must-have-mods!) and cleaned the official content (since Artmoor's mods are all cleaned already) The patches alone didn't help, so Live Another Life was the key in sorting out whatever the problem was.

Comment: Incidentally I used Steam Workshop in the end.

Comment: @AliceRees I use NMM to install and update mods. I find its updater and installer easier to use. I use [Wrye Bash](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/1840) to run BOSS, create a Bashed Patch and launch SKSE.

Comment: I've been able to create a character but the game crashes at about 1 minute of play time.

Comment: @AliceRees Try this: "*Go to `\SteamApps\common\skyrim` and open the `Skyrim` folder in there. The file you're looking for is called `SkyrimPrefs.ini` -  delete it...*" (from: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Skyrim#Crash_on_Launcher_or_Crash_when_Starting_Skyrim ) This will reset your preferences and might solve the crash. (Backup the file before deleting it.)

Comment: Sadly nope, no help.

Comment: Did you ever rearrange the load order after cleaning? That could be causing crashes if so. (Using the official launcher usually scrambles your load order. Always use a 3rd party plugin manager, and avoid the launcher like the plague.) Plugins can only count as "clean" if they don't change order relative to other plugins that touch the same content. If so, reinstall the DLC fresh, fix load order, then clean them one at a time starting from the top of the order.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie none of the cleaned DLC's changed order.

Comment: @AliceRees There is another SkyrimPrefs.ini in 'My Documents\My Games\Skyrim` - try deleting that too and let the game generate another one. (Backup it first before deleting it.)

Comment: @galacticninja nope, no luck.